# Which Canon lens to get, EF 24mm f/1.4L II or EF 50mm f/1.2L

Tags: lens

I own a Canon 6D Mark II, a Canon 24-105 f/2.8L II.

I would like to get a prime Canon lens for portraits that will be mostly full body to group pictures. I have a big family and enjoy taking photos of several people at at time to a full group.

The lenses I am considering are an EF 24mm f/1.4L II or an EF 50mm f/1.2L.

I have the 50mm at the moment (borrowed) but the 24mm attracts me because it's a wide angle lens. I guess that is my dilemma. I read as many pros and cons about the 2 lenses like everything else, but I still like to get one of the two for the max aperture of 1.2 or 1.4, and the price is about the same for either one.

I just love to take pictures but I don't know which one to get. I'm not getting it new.

Comment: Try searching the web and this site for lens's  best suited for portrait photography. Not only will you **learn about lens's for portrait photography** but you will learn why they are good for portrait photography thereby helping you to **do better portrait photography**.

Comment: By "portrait", do you mean "head shots", or "full-body" shots, or something in between? More specific details would be useful.

Comment: Mostly full  body to group pictures.  I have a big family and enjoy taking photos of several people at at time to a full group.

Comment: I have the 50mm at the moment (borrowed) but the 24mm attracts me because it's a wide angle lens.  I guess that is my dilemma. I read as many pros and cons about the 2 lenses like everything else, but I still like to get one of the two for the max aperture of 1.2 or 1.4, and the price is about the same for either one.

Comment: Step 1 to purchasing gear: Don't spend a dime until you can articulate your need. 24mm and 50mm are *vastly* different focal lengths. The fact that you have a need and you think that either of these two lenses may fill it means that you don't understand your need enough to spend this kind of coin. But hey, it's your cash. If it were me, I'd examine the shots you have taken from that 24-105 to see where most of your shots are to learn something about your shooting before making any decisions on new gear.

Comment: ***"Mostly full body to group pictures."*** You won't be shooting group portraits at f/1.4 or f/1.2. I'd be at f/2.8 at minimum, probably f/4. So, why does your 24-105 not work for this?

Comment: @Hueco Probably low light and a lack of realization that using f/1.4 or even f/2 for a group portrait in low light is just trading one set of problems for another set of problems. What the OP actually needs is some light. So buy a flash.

Comment: Where can I find 24-105 mm f/2.8L? I want one!

Comment: They are very different lenses. If you're taking full body or group photos, your subject distance will be large and you will not get the magical and nearly zero depth of field when shooting at f/1.2. And in a group photo, you don't want such a shallow DoF anyway because people faces won't all be within it. Rent both and play with it. I prefer the 24/1.2 because it's more flexible. But neither are flexible enough for groups, for which you ideally need the 24-70, 24-105 or 70-200 -- all zooms because you often don't have the luxury or time to move around to find a good framing.

Comment: I do appreciate the information guys.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Get this one, or one of its clones. It's the Canon 600EX RT-II.

[image]

Yeah, I understand you asked about lenses, but if you swap a 24mm f/1.4 or 50mm f/1.2 for your 24-105mm f/4 because you need a faster aperture due to lighting constraints you're just going to be trading one set of problems for another. You don't want to be shooting group portraits at anywhere near f/1.4 or even f/2 or f/2.8.

Even for solo portraits we don't usually open up the aperture wider than f/4 unless we're tightening the framing to a head and shoulders shot. For that kind of shot you need a longer focal length than 50mm, much less 24mm. Getting close enough to frame that tightly with wider angle lenses causes issues with [perspective](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/114679/15871) distortion that are not flattering to human faces.

If you're willing to spend what the two lenses you mentioned cost, then go for a setup like this:

[image]

You'll need a couple of 800WS to 1600WS monolights in large softboxes, a couple of 300-400WS monolights with basic reflectors, and stands for each of the flashes. You'll probably want to trigger them with a wireless radio trigger mounted on your camera's hot shoe. Be aware that different brands, or even different series within the same brand, use different radio protocols. You'll need to settle on a radio system and then insure that everything else you choose can work within that system, either via built-in radio receivers or by cable connection to a compatible radio receiver.

Get something like the Godox 2.4 GHz X-series for Canon that has flashes which include built-in radio receivers. The nice thing about Godox is that their entire system, from small manual hot-shoe mounted flashes all the way up to their largest studio monolights all use the same protocol and can all be controlled by a single trigger.

If you are in the U.S. you can buy from the Adorama *Flashpoint* system which is just the Godox system rebranded with different model numbers for the otherwise exact same devices. That way your service and support is based in NYC instead of China. You can use Godox and Flashpoint devices interchangeably. There are also several private nameplates in other world areas that are rebadged Godox products.

Comment: I like this answer a lot and it is basically my experience from shooting families at the studio, though we used Alien Bees for our overpower-ambient needs. Poh-tato Pah-tato.

Comment: @Hueco Alien Bee monolights are great, but they're not radio integrated at all, much less in the way Godox has included *everything* from small, shoe mounted manual only flashes all the way to HSS, TTL, high WS studio lights. ABs are still good if you're going to "set and forget" for a session such as school photos. Not so much if you're being more experimental in the studio with the same model and trying different looks. Paul Buff's death has apparently affected their customer service level a bit, too. It's still good, but I've heard it's not as great as it was when he was running things.